# htaccess redirect www to non www works but removing /cgi-bin/ from URL is breaking site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, cgi-bin

Have an odd issue, we are simply trying to redirect www to non www which there are countless ways of doing so in .htacess and all work except for some reason the rewrite is also removing /cgi-bin/ from the URL which we need otherwise the site breaks.  Example URL:

```
http://www.example.com/cgi-bin/band.cgi?BandNum$5
```

redirects to

```
http://exmaple.com/band.cgi?BandNum$5
```

Using the following htaccess rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I am thinking its something in the Apache conf affecting cgi-bin specifically which is causing issues with .htaccess rules but am unable to track it down, ideas?

Thank you!

Here is the full htaccess

```
Options -Indexes

#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cgi-bin/ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^item-(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*).html$ auction.php?title=$1&item=$2&country=$3&ccid=$4
RewriteRule ^item-(.*)_(.*)_(.*).html$ auction.php?title=$1&item=$2&country=$3
RewriteRule ^item-(.*)_(.*).html$ auction.php?title=$1&item=$2

redirect 301 /mrfest2007/index.html https://example.com/cgi-bin/gletter.cgi
```

Apache conf has:

```
<IfModule alias_module>
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/usr/local/apache/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>
```

and in the actual virtual host for the domain there is:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/username/public_html/cgi-bin/
```

Comment: There must be other rules/directives causing this. The rules you show don't remove anything beyond `www.`.

Comment: I added the full htaccess, nothing would cause it, that's why I think its something in apache conf but nothing stands out there either.

Comment: Is the `.htaccess` file inside the `cgi-bin` directory?

Comment: no its in the  doc root, public_html/.htaccess the  cgi-bin is public_html/cgi-bin

Comment: Could there be a `ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /public_html/` ?

Comment: In the apache conf there is, I am updating my original post with it

Comment: I've tested by commenting both of those out, restarting apache, and still same issue occurs.

Comment: did you try `%{REQUEST_URI}` instead of  `/$1` ? This is an extreme option, but could work until a solution found: `RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST} %{THE_REQUEST}" "^www\.(\S*)\s[A-Z]{2,6}\s(/\S+)" [NC]` \n `RewriteRule ^ "http://%1%2" [R=301,L]`